# Oracle order by numeric and alpha ex: 1, 1a, 1b, 2, 2c

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by

I have this data :

```
1
10
100
101
102
12
120
1a
1b
1c
2
3
4
```

and I would like to order like this:

```
1
1a
1b
1c
2
3
4
10
12
100
101
102
120
```

It's possible in Oracle ?

I tried this but it does not work with alphabetic characters

```
order by case when replace(translate(trim(COLUMN),'0123456789','0'),'0','') is null then to_number(COLUMN) end asc, COLUMN asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind the minor performance hit, a regexp is an easy solution.

```
-- sample data
with t as (select '1' as x from dual
            union select '10' from dual
            union select '100' from dual
            union select '101' from dual
            union select '102' from dual
            union select '12' from dual
            union select '120' from dual
            union select '1a' from dual
            union select '1b' from dual
            union select '1c' from dual
            union select '2' from dual
            union select '3' from dual
            union select '4' from dual)
-- query
select x
from t
-- order first by the leading numbers, then alphabetically
order by to_number(regexp_substr(x, '[0-9]*')), x;
```